# Problem in adding latitude and longitude value

Tags: iphone, ios, coordinates, cllocationmanager, mkreversegeocoder

when i change the latitude and longitude value of another location my app closes automatically help ?

```
if (1)
{
    CLLocationCoordinate2D cordi;
    cordi.latitude  =  45.574779;
    cordi.longitude = -122.685366;

    MKReverseGeocoder *coder = [[MKReverseGeocoder alloc] initWithCoordinate:cordi];
    coder.delegate = self;
    [coder start];
}
else
{
    [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(showWeather:) withObject:@"97217"];
}
```

Comment: Do you get an error message or stack trace in the console?  Look at Apple's sample app [CurrentAddress](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CurrentAddress/Introduction/Intro.html) to see how they declare, create and use MKReverseGeocoder.

Comment: Have you defined methods for both reverseGeocoder:didFailWithError: and reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Twelve47 Said, you should fully implement the [delegate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/MKReverseGeocoderDelegate), since both methods are not optional.

It sounds like you have only implemented the sucess method:

`– reverseGeocoder:didFindPlacemark:`

so when you change the location to somewhere than cant be geocoded, the fail methods gets called which causes a error.

Add this code:

```
- (void)reverseGeocoder:(MKReverseGeocoder *)geocoder didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
   NSLog(@"Geocoder failed with error: %@",error);
}
```